# Как можно сымитировать вариативный товар через простые?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.
Пришли сюда с надеждой, что кто-то сможет решить нашу дилемму.

Делаем сайт для доставки пиццы на Wordpress + Woocommerce. Все товары хранятся в программе [Poster](https://joinposter.com/) и синхронизируются на сайт.

Заказчик хочет иметь на сайте возможность переключатели для теста и размера пиццы. Пример на фото ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И столкнулись с такой проблемой, что из Poster'а физически не может сразу прилетать вариативный товар, только простой.

1. Простой товар пробовали руками менять на составной, но отваливается базовая цена, соответственно при синхронизации уже товар не обновляется.
2. Пробовали делать несколько товаров, которые отличаются только размером или тестом. Эти товары уже прописывали в кастомных полях (по типу поля Апсейл) и уже их выводить. Этот вариант также не устроил из-за обновления страницы и перехода на новую карточку товара.

Может у кого-то есть предложения по этим вариантам или какие-то другие решения этого вопроса. Будем рады любым ответам.

Comment: Это вопрос для UpWork, а не StackOverflow.

Comment: В постере для каждого варианта товара отдельная запись?

Comment: @Darth KYL, да в постере для каждого варианта отдельная запись